# Error 502 within WordPress Admin panel

Tags: wordpress, openshift

We’re having an issue in our website's WordPress editor where an Error 502 message pops up when we go to certain pages – for example, I’ve noticed it occurring when I try to go to the backup plugin page to restore a backup, as well as when I go to the add a new plugin page.

[Error 502 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1TQp.png)

We did a traceroute and determined the error is on our hosting provider’s side - openshift

Can someone walk me through how to fix this error? Full disclosure - not a coder (just handle admin for my company and general website upkeep falls into my role) so as detailed directions as possible would be a huge help as this is outside my wheel house. Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!, first i can see that the front page is too slow maybe its my internet connection!. for the 502 if it happens on specific page or with the admin panel only you may need to stop all your plugins or if you added something before the issue appear you need to remove it (maybe you have installed a plugin or something)

Comment: if you have not done any modification try to stop all plugins then activate it one by one and test your admin after each plugin to make sure everything is working correctly.